# How to display image? Django

Tags: django

I've tried inserting "static" in the tag but doesnt return the image. Rather it returns a white box. Users are able to upload their own pictures. The directory where this is stored is `Aviation -> Uploads -> Aircraft`. Where exactly am I going wrong?

**list.html**

```
<div class="box"><img src="{{ aircraft.image }}" />
```

**Settings. py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ map_path('static'),]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**View.py**

```
def list_aircraft(request):
  aircraft = Aircraft.objects.all()
  favorited_aircraft_ids = None

  if request.user.is_authenticated():
    favorited_aircraft_ids = list(FavoritedAircraft.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id).values_list('id', flat=True))
    print (favorited_aircraft_ids)

  return render(request, 'aircraft/aircraft_list.html', {
    'aircraft': aircraft,
    'favorited_aircraft_ids': favorited_aircraft_ids,
  })
```

**Model.py**

```
class Aircraft(AircraftModelBase):
    manufacturer = SortableForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    aircraft_type = SortableForeignKey(AircraftType)
    body = SortableForeignKey(Body)
    engines = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/aircraft", blank=True, null=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    maximum_range = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    passengers = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    maximum_altitude = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    cruising_speed = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    fuel_capacity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    wing_span = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    length = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

aircraft is a queryset (it could be lots of Aircraft objects)

```
aircraft = Aircraft.objects.all()
```

You must to iterate (in your template) over this queryset to access the real object, something like:

```
{% for a in aircraft %}
    <img src="{{ a.image.url }}" />
{% empty %}
    The aircarft queryset is empty
{% endfor %}
```

I assume that your model for Aircraft has a ImageField, so, to get the image url, you must use  "aircraft.image.url" if the ImageField is called "image". The "empty" template tag will show you if your queryset is empty. If the message "The aircarft queryset is empty" is not shown, then you should look the browser developer tool for any problem in the network distributions of media files

Comment: @HoshAdf Solution in this answer should work. Do you see any 404 errors? What do your browser's network logs say? Can you check the value of image `src` in your browser by *Inspect Element*? What is the value?

Comment: @Nazkter added!

Comment: It seems correct to me, my answer should work. you can try the edition of my answer to find what is your problem.